# Use p5.js functions inside global variables

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to have a file with global variables, for example:

```
function Globals() {

}

Globals.gravity = createVector(0, -9.81);
```

Unfortunately `p5.js` functions can only be used when they are declared inside `setup()` or `draw()` or are called from one of these functions.

My question is what would be the best approach to make globals easy to use?

My only idea is to make them functions, but that is not very pretty (you have to call function to get a value) and it is probably slow, because each access to a global variable requires making a call.
`Globals.gravity = function() { return createVector(0, -9.81); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, fortunately, you could use p5.js functions outside `setup()` and `draw()` function.

In order to use those functions, you need to call `new p5()` beforehand, like so ...

```
new p5(); //<-- call this

function Globals() {}
Globals.gravity = createVector(0, -9.81);
```

For more info, refer [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup)

Comment: @FCin Please note that it's not as simple as this. While this will solve your immediate problem, what you actually want to do is convert your sketch to use instance mode. Please see the link in the answer.